# How can I make curl ouput an echo message with IF statements from api json data from laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, curl

I'm trying to build an api like authorize.net with laravel api and curl. Fairly learning.

The API part is already done in laravel. But I want curl to output a message if status = 1 from the API data from database.

The API endpoint is https://pay.prufal.com/api/Exttransfer/d7ufllzO7CRipy3U/UGD00VkYriPV9TPW

If you go to this URL it shows the data from my database

This is my curl.php code on a separate PHP file.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
$url = "https://pay.prufal.com/api/Exttransfer/d7ufllzO7CRipy3U/UGD00VkYriPV9TPW";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$resp = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 
if($e = curl_error($ch)){
    echo e;
}
Else{
    $obj=json_decode($resp, true);
    print_r($obj);
    //Verify Payment
    if (array_key_exists("data", $obj)  && ($obj["status"] == "1")) {
        echo 'success paid';
    }
    Else
    {
    echo 'neverpaid';
    }
                                
                
}

?>
```

status = 1 in API data if you look at the data but curl keeps outputting the else statement to neverpaid instead of success paid in curl.php.

Comment: `array_key_exists("data", $obj)` - I don't see a key called `data` in that response.

Comment: there isn't any key called data existed in your array $obj so that's why you get the error

Answer (score 0):

The key "data" is not existed in an $obj array so try to search the key which is existed in the $obj array

Try this

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
$url = "https://pay.prufal.com/api/Exttransfer/d7ufllzO7CRipy3U/UGD00VkYriPV9TPW";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$resp = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 
if($e = curl_error($ch)){
    echo e;
}
Else{
    $obj=json_decode($resp, true);
    print_r($obj);
    //Verify Payment
    if (array_key_exists("payment_type", $obj)  && ($obj["status"] == "1")) {
        echo 'success paid';
    }
    Else
    {
    echo 'neverpaid';
    }
                                
                
}

?>
```